# Make list separated by date

Tags: php, list, codeigniter

I want to make a list of x things separate by the actual date example 08/02 and after it another list with the x things of 07/02, the dates are saved in the bd here is some of the code that i try to do..

```
 <h1 id="date-title"><?php echo $fecha1 ?></h1>
            <div id="news-block">
                <?php
                $nombre=null;
                foreach ($programas as $programa) {
            if($programa->ingreso==Date("Y-m-d")){
                    if ($programa->nombre!= $nombre) {
                        $nombre = $programa->nombre;
                        echo "<h3 id='news-title'>".$programa->nombre."</h3>";
                    }
                    echo "<ul id='news-content'>";
                    echo $programa->titulo;
                    echo " </ul>";
               }else
               {
                $fecha_menos24hs = date('m-d',time()-(24*60*60));
                 echo "<h1 id='date-title'>$fecha_menos24hs</h1>"; 
                if ($programa->nombre!= $nombre) {
                        $nombre = $programa->nombre;
                        echo "<h3 id='news-title'>".$programa->nombre."</h3>";
                    }
                    echo "<ul id='news-content'>";
                    echo $programa->titulo;
                    echo " </ul>";

               }
            }

            ?>
           </div>
```

The problem is that at the secod date its repeat this code "echo "$fecha_menos24hs"; " because the for each, may be can you reccomend me an better idea.. i dont know two foreachs..

Thanks for your time.

Comment: can you post the array which you are using and post what kind of output you are expecting.........

Comment: I would recommend doing this in two steps: first sort the array in the order you need to print, and THEN print it. Otherwise I guess you'll have to iterate through the entire list for every date you need, assuming you know the dates you want in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing he wants to close and start new lists (as in, manually closing tags), when a different date is found. This needs to be implemented separately even if the array is ordered.

Comment: Thats the idea Chris C , you said i have to have two for each?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you are looking for this output or something similar:

```
<h1 class="date_title">Date</h1>
<div class="news_block">
    <h3>News Title</h3>
    <ul class="news_content">
        <li>Article Content</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="news_block">
    <h3>News Title #2</h3>
    <ul class="news_content">
        <li>Article Content</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<h1 class="date_title">Date #2</h1>
....
```

The easiest way I can think of is to restructure your SQL results in the controller.

```
//Ordering by the date with newest first
$this->db->order_by('DATE_COLUMN', 'DESC');
$results = $this->db->get()->result_array();
$article_list = array(array());
foreach ($results as $key)
{
    $article_list[$key['DATE_COLUMN']][] = $key;
}
$this->data['articles'] = $article_list;
$this->load->view('DISPLAY', $this->data);
```

I would then use a couple of loops in your view to get your results.

```
<?php foreach($articles as $key => $value): ?>
<h1 class="date-title">$key</h1>
    <?php foreach($value as $key2): ?>
<div class="news_block">
    <h3><?php echo $key2['title']; ?></h3>
    <ul class="news_content">
        <?php echo $key2['content']; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```